# Unable to connect to s3 endpoint from Session Manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-neptune, aws-session-manager

I am trying to bulk load RDF N-triples data from S3 bucket into Neptune loader. I have created a S3 bucket, IAM Role, Endpoint and Neptune cluster as per the following link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/bulk-load-data.html.

To connect to Neptune instance, I have created a EC2 instance with Session Manager Enabled. I connected with Session Manager and executed following SPARQL ntriples insert command to ingest single data into Neptune instance, which worked fine.

```
curl -X POST --data-binary 'update=INSERT DATA { triples }' https://your-neptune-endpoint:port/sparql
```

But, when I try to execute bulk load data into Neptune DB from S3 bucket using below command, getting the following error,

**command executed in Session Manager**

```
curl -X POST \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    https://your-neptune-endpoint:port/loader -d '
    {
      "source" : "s3://bucket-name/File-name.nt",
      "format" : "ntriples",
      "iamRoleArn" : "arn:aws:iam::account-id:role/role-name",
      "region" : "us-east-1",
      "failOnError" : "FALSE",
      "parallelism" : "MEDIUM",
      "updateSingleCardinalityProperties" : "FALSE",
      "queueRequest" : "TRUE",
    }'
```

**Error**

{"detailedMessage":"Unable to connect to s3 endpoint. Provided source = s3://bucket-name/File-name.nt and region =us-east-1. Please verify your S3 configuration.","code":"InternalFailureException","requestId":"4xx-xxxxxxxxxxx-xx"}

I also verified S3 configuration and IAM role associated with Neptune DB, it seems to be correct. Am I missing any important configuration part? Can anyone help with this issue?

Comment: When you created the S3 VPC Endpoint, do you do so through the console?  If so, the console will default to adding the proper routes to your route table for sending S3 traffic through that endpoint.  If not, you may need to go back and add that route manually.

Comment: @TaylorRiggan Yes, I have created a VPC endpoint through the console with route tables.

Comment: Were you able to get the bulk load working?